# System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." z

Tags: c#, winforms

Ругается на     NameTest = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connection.Open();
        if (NamePredmet != listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT *FROM [Тесты] WHERE [Название предмета] = @Name", Connection);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", listBox1.SelectedItem);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            NamePredmet = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
           
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader[1].ToString());
            }

            

        }

        NameTest = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        Connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: listBox1.Items.Clear();?

Comment: После очистки списка вы пытаетесь взять выбранный элемент, а он null

Comment: Когда я чищу ,я начинаю выводить другие данные уже

Comment: Если записи не удалять ,они будут появляться вместе с другими

Comment: Вы можете задать `listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0` после добавления элементов.

Comment: Та ошибка исчезла ,но за ней появилась новая System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "InvalidArgument=Значение '0' недопустимо для 'SelectedIndex'.
Имя параметра: SelectedIndex"